# Give out and plot p-values for rpart decision-tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart, p-value

I want to plot a decision tree in R with rpart and fancyRpartPlot. The code is working, but I want to show the p-value of each split. When I execute the tree (last line of the code), I get the stars behind the nodes which usually indicate statistical significance - I guess this is the case here too. However, I want to access the calculated p-values and include them in the plot. I would be very grateful, if anyone has an idea on how to do this. Thanks!

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)

seatbelts <- Seatbelts
seatbelts <- as.data.frame(seatbelts)
unique(seatbelts$law)


seatbelts_tree <- rpart(law ~ ., data=seatbelts)
plot(seatbelts_tree, uniform = TRUE, margin = 0.5)
text(seatbelts_tree)

prp(seatbelts_tree)
fancyRpartPlot(seatbelts_tree, type=2)

seatbelts_tree
```

Answer (score 1):

The ouput of the above code contains the answer, that the * indicates a **terminal node** , which is harder to spot given text output depending on the format.

```
n= 192 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 192 20.244790 0.11979170  
   2) drivers>=1303 178  8.544944 0.05056180  
     4) front>=663 158  1.974684 0.01265823  
       8) kms< 18147.5 144  0.000000 0.00000000 *
       9) kms>=18147.5 14  1.714286 0.14285710 *
     5) front< 663 20  4.550000 0.35000000  
      10) PetrolPrice< 0.1134217 11  0.000000 0.00000000 *
      11) PetrolPrice>=0.1134217 9  1.555556 0.77777780 *
   3) drivers< 1303 14  0.000000 1.00000000 *
```

If you want p-values you should look into the `cpart` library. Here is a related question to it with a short explanation and further reading material.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255150/how-to-interpret-this-decision-tree/255156

Answer (score 0):

The stars in the print method of `rpart` highlight terminal nodes, not p values. A decision tree is a descriptive method. It is not designed to test hypotheses.